# Mapr Hbase file jar

Tags: mapr

hello  I'm new in learner in mapr , can someone give me a list of jars  or a pom.xml example file , for  developing  hbase apps, by the way i'm using sandbox version 5.0.0 for testing and thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Maven project file:

*Repository*

```
<repository>
  <id>mapr-maven</id>
  <url>http://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>
  <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
  <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
```

*Dependencies*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.98.9-mapr-1503-m7-4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also do you know if you are using HBase or MapR-DB tables in your application?

You can find a complete MapR-DB sample application here : https://github.com/tgrall/mapr-nosql-samples